# Q: org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.copyProperties(): How exact must the value types match?

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

When using org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.copyProperties(target, source) I have experienced that the following does not work:

```
String getValue() -> void setValue(Object)
```

even if there is only one "void setValue(...)" on the target. It seems to be required that the argument type of the target setter matches EXACTLY the return type of the source getter, and that it is not sufficient if the the target expects a super type of the source.

Is that true?

If so: What alternatives do I have when I need to implement a setter like

```
void setValue(Object)
```

and want to "fill" it from a bean object having only String properties?